# How to split on a character and keep value

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string:

"N8383"

I want to split on the character and maintain it to get:

```
["N", "8383"]
```

I tried the following:

```
"N8383".split(/[A-Z]/)
```

which gives me:

```
["", "8383"]
```

I want to match some more example strings like:

```
N344 344N S555 555S
```

Comment: what output are you expecting?

Comment: Do you want `"N8383".split(/[(A-Z])/) # => ["", "N", "8383"]`? I suspect not. See the doc for [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-split) with respect to capture groups, but I'm not sure you actually want to `split` here.

Comment: I want `["N", "8383"]`

Comment: what would you suggest instead?

Comment: Is this the only case? You could use `"N8383".split(/(?<=[A-Z])/)` this is a non capturing group that will split between "N" and "8383" but if there are more cases, edge cases, etc. we would need to know as this only applies to a single character `[A-Z]` followed by any characters that are not `[A-Z]`

Comment: In this case I want to support strings that could be `N8383` or `8383N`

Comment: @GreggHorton that is very important. Add this to your question. Preferably with a small set of Input -> output expectations. e.g. `"N8383" => ["N", "8383"]` and `"8383N" => ["8383","N"]` (more examples would be better especially if anything does not / might not match this pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String#split` is a bad fit for this problem for the reasons others have stated. I would approach it like this, using [`String#scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-scan) instead:

```
str_parts = "N8383".scan(/[[:alpha:]]+/)
num_parts = "N8383".scan(/[[:digit:]]+/)
```

This will give you something to work with if the strings contain multiple string parts and/or multiple numeric parts.

This expression:

```
%w[N344 344N S555 555S].map do |str|
  next str.scan(/[[:alpha:]]+/), str.scan(/[[:digit:]]+/)
end
```

Will return:

```
[
  [["N"], ["344"]],
  [["N"], ["344"]],
  [["S"], ["555"]],
  [["S"], ["555"]]
]
```

Although you are scanning each string twice, I think it's a better solution than 1. trying to come up with a complex regex that backtracks to return the parts in the right order, or 2. reprocessing the results to put the parts in the right order. Especially if the strings are as short as they are in the examples you've provided. That being said, if scanning each string twice really rankles you, here's another way to do it:

```
str_parts, num_parts = str.scan(/([[:alpha:]]+)|([[:digit:]]+)/).transpose.each(&:compact!)
```

Comment: I wonder if order is important? since "S555" AND "555S" produce the same results in this case. I would assume your answer is better after having re read the question

Comment: thank you so much! this is exactly what I was looking for and allows me to use the characters and numbers later in a way that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Okay given the examples you could use the following regex

```
   /(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])/
```

This will look look ahead (`?=`) for a single character `[A-Z]` or look behind (`?<=`) for a single character `[A-Z]`. Since these are zero length assertions the split is placed between the characters rather than being the character. e.g.

```
  %w{N8383 N344 344N S555 555S}.map {|s| s.split(/(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])/) } 
  #=> [["N", "8383"], ["N", "344"], ["344", "N"], ["S", "555"], ["555", "S"]]
```

However this regex is specific to the given cases and does not offer any real deviation from the given cases e.g I have no idea of desired output for "N344S" but right now it will be `["N", "344" ,"S"]` and worse yet `"NSS344S"` will be `["N", "S", "S", "344", "S"]`

Answer (score 1):

```
def doit(str)
 str.scan(/\d+|\p{L}+/)
end

doit "N123"   #=> ["N", "123"]
doit "123N"   #=> ["123", "N"]
doit "N123M"  #=> ["N", "123", "M"]
doit "N12M3P" #=> ["N", "12", "M", "3", "P"]
doit "123"    #=> ["123"]
doit "NMN"    #=> ["NMN"]
doit ""       #=> []
```